# How can I conditionally do POST request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post

First, please look at the code.

```js
    const [detailTitle, setDetailTitle] = useState(actionItemArray[activeRow].TITLE);
    const [detailDesc, setDetailDesc] = useState(actionItemArray[activeRow].DESCRIPTION);

    //Unix time 변환 함수
    function getUnixTime(t) {
        const date = new Date(t * 1000);
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const month = '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1);
        const day = '0' + date.getDate();
        return year.toString().substr(-2) + '-' + month.substr(-2) + '-' + day.substr(-2);
    }

    const [detailStartDate, setDetailStartDate] = useState(getUnixTime(actionItemArray[activeRow].START_DATE));
    const [detailDueDate, setDetailDueDate] = useState(getUnixTime(actionItemArray[activeRow].DUE_DATE));

    const [detailPriority, setDetailPriority] = useState(actionItemArray[activeRow].P_PK);
    const [detailStep, setDetailStep] = useState(actionItemArray[activeRow].STEP_PK);

    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [disableTag, setDisableTag] = useState(true);

    const detailTitleChange = (e) => {
        setDetailTitle(e.target.value);
    };

    const detailDescChange = (e) => {
        setDetailDesc(e.target.value);
    };

    const detailStartDateChange = (e) => {
        setDetailStartDate(e.target.value)
    };

    const detailDueDateChange = (e) => {
        setDetailDueDate(e.target.value)
    };
```

and for Priority and Step, I gave onChange event as it is a Select Form.

```js
    const updateActionItem = () => {
        const url = '/api/work/update-action-item';
        const data = {
            ACTION_PK : actionItemArray[activeRow].ACTION_PK,
            OWNER_PK : actionItemArray[activeRow].owner.USER_PK,
            TITLE : detailTitle,
            DESCRIPTION: detailDesc,
            START_DATE : detailStartDate,
            DUE_DATE : detailDueDate,
            P_PK : detailPriority,
            STEP_PK : detailStep,
            updateCols: ['TITLE', 'DESCRIPTION']
        };
        post(url, data)
        .then((res) => {
            alert('수정되었습니다');
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    };
```

this function is for a POST request. I send every edited data to DB.

But data object, you can see updateCols : [].

In this array, I have to put properties that have been changed.

For example, If I change TITLE, DESCRIPTION and START_DATE, I have to change the array to

```js
updateCols : ['TITLE', 'DESCRIPTION', START_DATE]
```

I am having trouble with this POST request form as I think it is impossible to track things down every time.

Someone might edit only TITLE, someone might edit every property. That means I have to change POST request form conditionally.

I need some wisdom. Please Help!

Comment: You need the state to track down the original data. When you first get the data, that response gets saved in the state. I guess the user will have some sort of input to change the data. So for every input, you set the default value to that state previously updated in you GET request, then, if the user changes any input, the data sent in your PUT request will be the same but with the changes made by the user. 
In order to help you better, you will need to add more code to your question, that is not enough.

Comment: Where do you store title, description etc.? And how you determine that the data is changed? From your code example it's not visible to give advice

Comment: @Oleg My bad. I will edit so that everyone can review it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your data in state before posting.
When you post the next time, compare the new data with the old state and hence create the updateCols using Array.prototype.push().
You can use ternary operators to compare the values.

```
   const [old, setOld] = useState({});
       
    const updateActionItem = () => {
         const url = '/api/work/update-action-item';
         let data = {
             ACTION_PK : actionItemArray[activeRow].ACTION_PK,
             OWNER_PK : actionItemArray[activeRow].owner.USER_PK,
             TITLE : detailTitle,
             DESCRIPTION: detailDesc,
             START_DATE : detailStartDate,
             DUE_DATE : detailDueDate,
             P_PK : detailPriority,
             STEP_PK : detailStep,
             updateCols : []
         };
         
         data.ACTION_PK!==old.ACTION_PK?data.updateCols.push('ACTION_PK'):null;
         data.OWNER_PK!==old.OWNER_PK?data.updateCols.push('OWNER_PK'):null;
         data.TITLE!==old.TITLE?data.updateCols.push('TITLE'):null;
         data.DESCRIPTION!==old.DESCRIPTION?data.updateCols.push('DESCRIPTION'):null;
         data.START_DATE!==old.START_DATE?data.updateCols.push('START_DATE'):null;
         data.DUE_DATE!==old.DUE_DATE?data.updateCols.push('DUE_DATE'):null;
         data.P_PK!==old.P_PK?data.updateCols.push('P_PK'):null;
         data.STEP_PK!==old.STEP_PK?data.updateCols.push('STEP_PK'):null; 
         
         setOld(data);
         
         post(url, data)
         .then((res) => {
             alert('수정되었습니다');
             console.log(res);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error)
         });
     };
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what your code does and how it helps the OP. Answers with "try this" and similar text are rarely helpful to anyone but the OP, and Stack Overflow is supposed to help everyone who comes across the answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, okay i updated the answer